# Regex split string at specific set of characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string of this nature `Set 1 (2) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]`. How can I make a regex that starts after (**important that it's after or I can just add it back**) every `)` character and optionally ends at a `]` character, so splitting the string would look something like this?

```
Set 1 (2) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]
-> [Set 1 (2)], [Set 2 (2)], [Set 3 (2)], [Set 4 (2)]
```

There might be some empty characters and trailing whitespaces in the created array when using regex but I can remove that.
My current try is something like `/\)(\s+).+(\]?)/gm` but due to the `.+` being greedy It goes all the way to the end for each match like so:

```
Set 1 (2) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]
-> Set 1 (2{) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]}
-> [Set 1 (2]
```

It also includes the `)` when splitting which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const s = "Set 1 (2) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]";
const m = s.match(/[^)]+(?:\))/g);
console.log(m)
```

To handle the leading whitespace:

```js
const s = "Set 1 (2) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]";
const m = s.match(/(?<= |^)[^)]+(?:\))/g);
console.log(m)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qG6G57/1

Comment: The first one works! the second one doesn't sadly it removes the first `Set` from the string. But I think it should be fine to just use the trim function with a map.

Comment: For leading whitespace you could just nap through the matches and trim the string.

Comment: @Apoqlite woops sorry, it's fixed now!!

Comment: For what the non-capture group?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(?<!\S).*?\)
\b.*\)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/VVlACn/1)

---

- `(?<!\S)` = Negative lookbehind to assert position is not preceded by a non-whitespace char;
- `.*?\)` - 0+ (lazy) characters upto a literal closing paranthesis.

The difference with the alternative `\b.*\)` is to use a word-boundary, but I'm not sure if that goes well with your actual data.

---

```js
var s = 'Set 1 (2) Set 2 (2) Set 3 (2) Set 4 (2) [Choose Two]';
var m = s.match(/(?<!\S).*?\)/g);
console.log(m)
```

Comment: I like the `(?<!\S)` idea, but mentioning that [`\S`](https://regex101.com/r/RXTRcl/1) can already suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to use `String.split` with this regex:

```
/(?<=\))/g
```

It simply looks behind for a `)` and then splits the text into an array.

However, you then need to remove the last item in the array (which will contain `[Choose Two]`).

Then you have array with each Set.

You can play with it [here](https://bak-o-soft.dk/RegExp/JSRegExpBuilder/Xf3qmw).